# Change R formula notation sorting?

Tags: r, sorting

Is there a way to resort the output from the formula notation in R:

My specific example is the following:

```
library('doBy')
summaryBy(carbon + nitrogen ~ class, data = samples, FUN=c(mean,sd,length))
```

gives me a dataframe with the following columns:

```
class, carbon.mean, nitrogen.mean, carbon.sd, nitrogen.sd, carbon.length, nitrogen.length
```

but I would like to have:

```
class, carbon.mean, carbon.sd, carbon.length, nitrogen.mean....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reorder the columns of your dataframe post hoc by name like this:

```
df = df[,c("class", "carbon.mean", "carbon.sd", "nitrogen.mean")]
```

Comment: ok, that works, but with many variables it doesn't ease the job.